# How do I change Server Charset in mysql (LAMP Stack)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, settings, lamp

I have a project I've been working on, and on my webhotel it works perfectly.
But I recently setup a LAMP stack to be able to work on it offline, and I am having trouble with the charset. Norwegian letters like æ - ø - å turns into symbols like �.

There are 1000 results when i try to google this problem, and i've tried alot of them without luck. I can say with certainty that it is not a Apache2 problem, or a PHP problem. It seems like there something fishy with my mysql/phpadmin configuration.

All my databases are set to charset UTF-8, but i noticed on the frontpage of phpmyadmin that the server-charset is wrong. I suspect that this is the problem, but how do i change this?

See the attatched photo, on the top right under "Database-tjener" at the bottom, it says 
Tjener-tegnsett: cp1252 West European (latin1), but probably should say UTF-8.

Again, how to i change this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLsrm.png)

Comment: So, I finally stumbled upon the answer to my own question. And I was right, this was the thing causing my problems.

For anyone looking for the same answer to this problem, here is what I did.

I had to add a couple of lines to my my.cnf file located in /etc/mysql/my.cnf

The Lines I added to the end was the following:

[mysqld]
character-set-server = utf8
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci

Now Æ Ø Å works properly :)